Polyfill warning from Google; PHPMailer and PHP dotenv affected
I got a warning from Google saying that my website is using Polyfill framework on Google Maps: "Notification Title: [Security Alert]: Polyfill.io Issue for Google Maps Platform users". It advised users to remove Polyfill.io, see link: https://www.kaspersky.com/blog/polyfill-io-service-supply-chain-attacks/51635/
After looking though my codebase(s) I have found other places where the Polyfill framework is used, like PHPMailer (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer, click on the composer.json file) and PHP dotenv (https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv, click on the  composer.json file).
Here is more information on why it's advised to remove Polyfill, see link: https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/issues/4363
I contacted the team at PHP dotenv just now, and so I'm still awaiting a response. I may have found a good replacement simply called dotenv, see link: https://github.com/symfony/dotenv. I cannot swear by this solution as I haven't had the opportunity to try it yet.
The problem is I haven't found a good alternative to PHPMailer.
Is anyone else facing the same problem? Any solutions yet?
PS: Just how severe is this? To put it short, it seems my visitors can be directed to shady betting websites and/or give up data unwaveringly, right...?
EDIT: I'm sorry if I scared any other newbies on PHP out there. Here is another Stack Overflow answer regarding this issue: [Security Alert]: Polyfill.io Issue for Google Maps Platform users in Angular
Please see Arthur Boucher's answer below!

You should replaced it asap. It is listed with a score 7.2/10 wich is classified as a high risk.
https://www.opencve.io/cve/CVE-2024-38526

I have remove all references, however I am concerned that this will affect the visitors using the website I'm developing. Is it as simple as just removing all references in the composer.json files?

"where the Polyfill framework is used, like PHPMailer" - are you sure? polyfill.io is a JS thing, PHPMailer is not

I think yes, but I am not an expert. Luckily the webshops I maintain were not effected. Best bet would be if you test it safely in your dev environment so figure things out properly

I'm not sure of anything, that's why I'm asking, but Google and Kaspersky (see links above) seem pretty sure

Why do you think that? Please add all details to your question by editing it

What more details are you thinking of, please? Glad to add more if I can!

Plase share where Google or Kaspersky state that PHPMailer or vlucas/dotenv are vulnerable. Both are highly used packages, and if they were vulnerable, you would find issues in their bug tracker or new releases with bugfixes related to the given problem

Ok, I understand what you mean. No I haven't seen any warnings regarding this on their own websites, however when you are new to PHP this stuff is scary... I'll let this question remain here (downvotes risked) in case anyone else new to PHP faced the same concerns

Follow up question: Then why are GMaps not providing any other solution then saying that I should remove any references to Polyfill.io? Couldn't they simply advise to update asap? Or did I miss that information somehow?

The google warning was trying to get you to do two things : update or remove libraries that contain links to polyfill.io, and remove all (if any) references to polyfill.io in code you had written yourself.

"when you are new to PHP this stuff is scary" - rest assured: PHP is not involved after all in this case, as this is a pure FE issue

There seems to be some confusion between the website polyfill.io and the concept of a polyfill. A polyfill is simply a library that adds backwards-compatibility to modern language or library features. The polyfills used in the PHP libraries you're linking to aren't provided by polyfill.io, and thus aren't affected by the issue.

Ok, that makes sense considering what I've read here and there. It's just so frightening to try to understand this when you are relatively new to PHP. Thanks a bunch! (I will mark your answer as correct if no contradictory information shows up...)

Yep, this is correct.
